# Image taken by the camera is of low resolution in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

When I take a picture without using the software I am creating, I get a high-resolution image. But when I use the program I am developing, my image is of low quality.
Please see how I implement it in Kotlin

```
private fun openCamera() {
    val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val imageBitmap = data?.extras?.get("data") as? Bitmap
        imageBitmap?.let {
            val file = File(requireContext().filesDir, "image.jpg")
            FileOutputStream(file).use { output ->
                it.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, output)
            }

            saveImageToGallery(requireContext(), imageBitmap)

            // Display a toast to indicate image saved successfully
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Image saved to internal storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}

private fun saveImageToGallery(context: Context, imageBitmap: Bitmap?) {
    val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
    val fileName = "IMG_$timeStamp.jpg"

    val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
        put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
    }

    val imageUri = context.contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)

    imageUri?.let {
        val outputStream: OutputStream? = context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(it)
        outputStream?.use { stream ->
            imageBitmap?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream)
        }
        outputStream?.close()

        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, arrayOf(imageUri.path), null, null)
    }
}
```